# How should I handle foreign keys for spouses in a persons table?

Tags: database-design

I have a table representing members of my organization.  I would like to indicate if a member is a partner of another member, as my wife and I are.  The table has a column named "person_key" and another named "spouse_key".  If I am member 1 and my wife is member 2, my person_key would be 1 and my spouse_key would be 2, and her person_key would be 2 and spouse_key would be 1.  Spouse_key would be configured as a foreign key relating to the person_key field.

But it seems to me that it would be hard to write any query that relies on that foreign key relationship without getting confused by that circle. Would it better to have a separate table named "partners" that would just have two columns, one for each person, both foreign keys into the members table?

Comment: Having a separate `Partner` table is a possibility since it will only have a few rows.  I imagine the spouse foreign key will be `null` for the vast majority of the members.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Person PR exists.
--
person {PR}
    PK {PR}
```

---

Note that relation (logic) `_ is spouse of _`
is symmetrical, i.e., if
`X is spouse of Y`, then is also true that `Y is spouse of X`.
This means that only one row is needed in the spouse table.
Note the `check` constraint. When inserting, swap person `IDs`
if necessary to make sure `X < Y`.

```
-- Person X is spouse of person Y.
--
spouse {X, Y}
    PK {X}
    AK {Y}

CHECK (X < Y)

FK1 {X} REFERENCES person {PR}
FK2 {Y} REFERENCES person {PR}
```

Also note that constraints on `spouse` will
*not prevent* this type of a problem, you'll have to prevent
it on the application level:

```
spouse  X   Y
        -----
        5   7
        7   9
```

---

To find a spouse of a specific person `the_person`.

```sql
-- Person X is spouse of person Y.
--
SELECT X
     , Y
FROM spouse
WHERE X = the_person
   OR Y = the_person
```

---

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```