# How can I implement a mutual friendship relationship in a database?

Tags: sql, database-design, many-to-many, relationship, data-integrity

I am designing a database schema for a social network
and need to implement **mutual friend relationships** between users in a database.

But what is the best way to represent such a relationship in the database? Is it even possible?

As an example, I will take [a sample from Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations).
**The follower relationship** is implemented there like this, although it doesn't guarantee reciprocity:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "User" (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"User_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);
CREATE TABLE "_UserFollows" (
    "A" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    "B" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

```js
model User {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String?
  followedBy Follows[] @relation("following")
  following  Follows[] @relation("follower")
}

model Follows {
  follower    User @relation("follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  Int
  following   User @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId Int

  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}
```

How can I ensure data integrity and atomicity of changes? Additionally, how can I make sure that when a relationship is deleted from one side, the relationship from the other side is also deleted?

Comment: Similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916498/how-should-i-handle-foreign-keys-for-spouses-in-a-persons-table/72928676#72928676

Comment: Looks fine. If Alice is deleted, all of the "Alice Follows" and "follows Alice" will be deleted, by the cascading delete. Did you want something different to happen, or something extra to happen?

Comment: @Ben Well, the question is how to implement two-way mutual relationships that can be linked and unlinked from the side of any of these two entities.